# How to pivot dataframe and transpose 1 row

Tags: python, pandas

I want to pivot this dataframe and convert the columns to a second level multiindex or column.

Original dataframe:

```
    Type        VC  C   B   Security
0   Standard    2   2   2       A
1   Standard    16  13  0       B
2   Standard    52  35  2       C
3   RI          10  10  0       A
4   RI          10  15  31      B
5   RI          10  15  31      C
```

Desired dataframe:

```
    Type            A   B  C  
0   Standard VC     2   16 52
1   Standard C      2   13 35
2   Standard B      2   0  2
3   RI       VC     10  10 10
11  RI       C      10  15 15
12  RI       B      0   31 31
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Also see [How to make pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Answer (score 0):

You could try as follows:

- Use [`df.pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) and then transpose using [`df.T`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25.0/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.T.html).
- Next, chain [`df.sort_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) to rearrange the entries, and apply [`df.swaplevel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html) to change the order of the MultiIndex.
- Lastly, consider getting rid of the `Security` as `columns.name`, and adding an `index.name` for the unnamed variable, e.g. `Subtype` here.
- If you want the MultiIndex as columns, you can of course simply use [`df.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) at this stage.

```
res = (df.pivot(index='Security', columns='Type').T
       .sort_index(level=[1,0], ascending=[False, False])
       .swaplevel(0))

res.columns.name = None
res.index.names = ['Type','Subtype']
print(res)

                   A   B   C
Type     Subtype            
Standard VC        2  16  52
         C         2  13  35
         B         2   0   2
RI       VC       10  10  10
         C        10  15  15
         B         0  31  31
```